# Dynamic Parameter Pass on where clause using where clause

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i m trying  to pass dynamic condition on where clause but when i pass dynamic string on list where clause it gives complied error .

Actually i am try in to list filteration with multiple condition that all are not fixed so if anyone have suggestion then please tell me

My code :-

```
  string condition = string.Empty;
  condition += "Packages[0].PackagePrice.FinalPrice>300 && Packages[0].PackagePrice.FinalPrice < 600";
  var studentQuery = searchResponse.HotelsSearchResponse.Result.Where(p=>condition);
```

Comment: It is not clear what type you are dealing with here `searchResponse.HotelsSearchResponse.Result` Is that XML or Json from a service call or is it an EntityFramework entity or...?

Comment: yes it is service call and it will return list type so 'searchResponse.HotelsSearchResponse.Result' its a list type

Comment: `List<T>` has a second type -- the `T` part.  It might help to show your all of your class code.  It is not totally clear what condition you are actually trying to impose.  Do you want to impose that FinalPrice condition(s) on all rows in the dataset?

Comment: actually i use one api  from that we get a response . I WANT ONLY HOW DYNAMIC CONDITION WE WILL APPEND ON "LIST WHERE" CLAUSE SO IF U HAVE ANY IDEA THEN PLEASE SUGGEST ME THANKS.:)

Comment: Just trying to help. From what you have posted it is NOT clear what condition you are trying to impose.  Without more detail I think you will find it difficult to get *anyone* to help you with this.